# mysql how to best set up tables where relation is one to several

Tags: mysql

I was trying a set up for my tables, which seemed simpler to me, but I am not managing to find the proper way.

This is to calculate after sales costs for vehicles where each vehicle will receive one of each of a sub-group of services from a price list to make up the total after sales cost.

Please see the scenario below:

Table AfterSalesPriceList would be like:

```
as_id   as_description      as_value

1       service kit1          1000
2       service kit2          1500
3       service kit3          2000
.......
10      repair kit1           5000
11      repair kit2           8000
12      repair kit3           9000
.....
21      pneu 1                1500
22      pneu 2                2500
23      pneu 3                4000
.....
31      battery 1              500
32      battery 2              800
33      battery 3              1000
```

Now, in another table? I would place which of these services each vehicle will receive.Each vehicle has to have one and ONLY 1 of each item from service, repair, pneu, battery,etc, like in a Table VehicleAS:

```
vehicle_id 1    service kit1, repair kit 2, pneu 3, battery 1
vehicle_id 2    service kit2, repair kit 2, pneu 1, battery 2
etc.....
```

Of course, this does not work in mysql, at least far as I know.

Is there a way to do this in mySql without the need to break apart Table After Sales in multiple tables, one for each subset (one for service, another for repair, another for battery, etc).

It will certainly work with exploding the AfterSalesPriceList Table, but I am trying to make it what seems to me more logical, ie, have all After Sales prices in a single table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a one to many relationship.  Both tables will have primary keys.  The child/many table will have a FOREIGN KEY column whose value will point back to the primary key in the parent/one table.

You'll find all the children that belong to the parent by doing a JOIN on parent primary key and child foreign key.

Comment: Thanks duffymo. I believe both you and legend got me in the right track, but I am giving you the result as it seems you came in first.

Answer (score 1):

Table `AfterSalesPriceList` seems to be OK.

Your another Table `VehicleAS` however can have

```
vehicle_id, as_id FOREIGN KEY (as_id) REFERENCES AfterSalesPriceList(as_id)
```

it can have multiple rows for a `vehicle_id` for each service it has used.

Comment: Thanks legend, I did not quite get why or what I would put in the column REFERENCES. The primary key for table VehicleAS would be a 2 column combining vehicle_id and as_id, right?